# face recognition opencv got type tuple error

Tags: python, opencv

cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h),font,255);
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) using python 3.7

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create();
rec.read("recognizer\\trainingData.yml")
id=0
font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,5,1,0,4
while(True):
  ret,img=cam.read();
  gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
  for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    if(id==1):
        id="x"
    cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h),font,255);
cv2.imshow("Face",img);
if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
   break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroy.AllWindows()
```

Comment: The error looks pretty clear to me. The third parameter should be integer, but you passed in tuple.

Comment: I’m new to python could u show how to correct this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows the line where it's coming from

```
cv2.putText(img,str(id),(x,y+h),font,255)
```

The fourth parameter is expected to be a font object, but you've initialised it to a tuple here:

```
font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,5,1,0,4
```

I believe font should be only

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
```

Look at the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576).

Btw, you don't need semicolons in python.